# datetimepicker popup hiding behind the container dialog box

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using this picker for my projects and I need to change the z index value of the picker, since its popping up behind a modal window, I want to increase the z index of the datetimepicker. I have currently added the zIndex propert inside the definition of the datetimepicker like this

```
jQuery(function() {
                       jQuery( "#from_date" ).datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                           showOn: "button",
                           zIndex:9999,
                            buttonImage: "/gra/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png",
                           buttonImageOnly: true });
               });
```

which is higher than the z index of the popup dialog inside which the datepicker button is placed but its not coming on top.
Which other places in the css style do I need to set the z index value apart from the definition?

**Update**: I used Firebug and found out the cause, but not the solution. The dialog box z-index is 1001, which I know as I have set that in the css. But the date-picker z-index value is 91 and I tried to search the class `ui-datepicker-div` but cannot find any class which has z-index value of 91 right now, there was a #search class with zindex as 91, and I changed it to 9999 (thinking thats the one its inheriting from), but it still again shows the value 91 in firebug..??
The classes associated wit the datepicker html component are

```
<div id="" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" ... z-index=91....>
<html for date picker>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using firebug, take a look with that and see what its z-index is actually being rendered as, compared to the element that is being rendered on top of it.  (You might want to put an example on jsfiddle, too...)

Comment: Are you able to provide an URL to your website or an example on jsfiddle.net? There must be a CSS issue for sure.

Comment: I had the same problem. Do the sliders for the time work? I can change the time by clicking on the slider but no by dragging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the big problem with zIndices.

```
<div style='position:relative'id="global-container">
    <div style='position:relative;z-index:1'id="container-1">
        <div style='position:relative;z-index:50'id="content-1"> content 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div style='position:relative;z-index:2'id="container-2">
        <div style='position:relative;z-index:2'id="content-2"> content 2 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may assume that `#content-2` will appear below `#content-1` but the problem is that z-indices are compared within their relative containers.  So the z-indices taken into count are `#container-1` and `#container-2`.  I would suggest a layer just for popups.  Something with an incredibly high z-index that is within the global container.  No matter what then it will override.

Now in ie7, as far as i can tell, its just whoever has highest z-index, but in modern browsers it depends on the entire chain, hence ui layer is needed for popups.

Youtube iframes will just dominate any z-index popups, at least i cannot figure out how to get around that... yet.

Comment: Look at every single parent.  Verify that their z-index.  There is not really a magic bullet.  You can try to check out google chrome which can tell you which styles are being overridden.